# How to parse a Java String as a literal block in YAML

Tags: java, parsing, annotations, yaml, snakeyaml

I need to parse only the Java Strings `description`,`instructions` as literal blocks ( `|`) in yaml,as both the above variables can contain multiline inputs and parse `infoId` as a usual string. I am using `snakeyaml` as the yaml library. How do I achieve the above? Is there any annotation that I need use for this?

*Pojo class*

```
public class Info {

private String infoId;
private String description;
private String instructions;

// Setters and getters
}
```

*parsing class*

```
...
Info info = new Info();
info.setDescription(descriptionWithMultilines);
info.setIntructions(instructionsWithMultilines);

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
String yamlString = yaml.dumpAs(info, Tag.MAP, DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
...
```

Comment: Could you please add an example how do you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude specific properties you can achieve it by using a custom [Representer](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/raw/default/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.java) class

this short snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Info info = new Info();
    info.setInfoId("demo");
    info.setDescription("foo\nbar");
    info.setInstructions("one\ntwo");

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new InfoRepresenter());
    String yamlString = yaml.dumpAs(info, Tag.MAP, DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
    System.out.println(yamlString);
}

private static class InfoRepresenter extends Representer {
    @Override
    protected NodeTuple representJavaBeanProperty(Object javaBean, Property property, Object propertyValue,
            Tag customTag) {
        if (javaBean instanceof Info && "infoId".equals(property.getName())) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return super.representJavaBeanProperty(javaBean, property, propertyValue,
                    customTag);
        }
    }
}
```

produces following output

```
description: |-
  foo
  bar
instructions: |-
  one
  two
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, However, I need to deserialize `infoId`as well. (`infoId` as normal String and `description` and `instructions` as literal blocks). Could you please help me resolve this. And sorry for not clearing mentioning the above in question.

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Taken your updated question `above variables ('description', 'instruction') can contain multiline inputs and parse 'infoId' as a usual string` your posted snippet would already do exactly this. So please update your question and add an example with the value for the three variables and how you expect the output to be formatted.